# Significantly greater chance of missing appointments in warm weather?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

Over a period of years, a person has 74 appointments. They inadvertently miss 5 of these.

The 5 missed appointments all occur in warmer weather.  Of the total 74,  44 of these appointments are in warmer weather, and 30 are in cooler weather. This distribution is because of the seasons – there are more warmer months than cooler. However there is little difference between the overall monthly average of appointments between the warmer and cooler months, 6.29 average per month vs. 6 respectively.

The end question is: what is the probability / likelihood that the missed appointments occurring on warmer days was or wasn’t by chance?

Is this the same probability question as the following:

a person is asked to select 5 cards at random out of a pack of 74 cards, 44 of which are red, and 30 black … and what is the probability they select 5 red cards?

Using a sequentially reduced probability as red cards are removed, the combined probability of all cards being red:

0.595 * 0.589 * 0.583 * 0.577 * 0.571  =  0.0674

And is this the correct way to look at it? Or should the total no. of appointments, warmer & cooler days reduce as time goes on?

Which is the better way to answer the end question as above?

Comment: It seems you are trying to do Fisher's Exact Test for data in a $2 \times 2$ table, but it is not clear whether you want a one- or two-sided test. // You ask for a particular hypergeometric probability, which is $({44\choose 5}{30\choose 0})/{74 \choose 5} = .0674$ and can be evaluated in terms of factorials. Perhaps review both topics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can instinctively or logically grasp at some concepts involved but don’t perhaps know quite what language to use.

Null hypothesis: there is no relationship between missed appointments and warmer weather.

However that doesn’t appear to be the case, the missed / warmer combination appears over-represented. But obviously in order for the null to be unlikely I need to establish the probability that arrangement may have simply occurred by chance.

The topics you suggest are very helpful / encouraging. Will have a better read of them in the morning.

Comment: The issue is whether categorical variable _Keeps Appointment_ (Yes or No) is independent of categorical variable _Temperature_ (Warm or Cool). The null hypothesis is that they are independent.

Comment: Thank you, that's clearer. In terms of one or two sided I _think_ it's one sided, because the warm, cool demarcation sits on the average daytime max. temp for the regional climate. i.e cool sits below & warm on average or above.

Comment: Not completely sure how one- or two sided fits in but  1. Ha: there is relationship between missed appointments and warmer weather  2. Ha: there is relationship, contingency between the 2 variables, Keeps Appointment & Temperature  Latter better, in that it doesn’t use data to determine exact nature of Ha, and all round more open, less biased.

Comment: OK. What I've learned & established so far (I think):  the data is 2 x 2 table of categorical variables. Null hypothesis: the two variables are independent. Alternative hypothesis: the two variables are dependent / there is relationship. And the questions I’m asking, sort of,  are: 1. does the observed distribution deviate off the distribution expected if the null hypothesis were true? 2a. if so, by how much? 2b. is this statistically significant?

Comment: Finally, because of the nature of the data (small numbers etc.) the Fisher Exact Test is the most appropriate. The one-sided test looks at all the possibilities that are even more extreme in one direction. You then add these p values to the .0674 and ask, are these above 0.05? Obviously yes, so there does appear to be an association but it's not statistically significant using this test. I hope I've understood all this correctly.

Comment: Seems you are on the right track.